# Drawing a tetrahedron with 4 triangles with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rotation

I decided to make a tetrahedron manually(4 triangles) and rotate it. It kinda work, the only problem is that one of the triangles is never drawn. In my example code the front triangle(red) is drawn first, but when I render it, it never appears. Instead half of the left triangle(white) and right triangle(blue) appear. However when I change the code and put the three vertices of the front triangle after the the vertices of the other triangles, I do get the front triangle. Nevertheless one of the other two triangles disappear. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>

float posx = 0;
float posy = 0;

void drawLines(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //THIS ROTATES THE WHOLE SCENCE
    /*glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(posx, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);*/

    //THIS ROTATES ONLY THE OBJECTS INSIDE THE GLPUSHMATRIX AND GLPOPMATRIX FUNCTIONS
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(posx, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    //TETAEDRON BY HAND
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    //front triangle
    glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( -5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 5.0f,  -5.0f, 0.0f);

    //right side triangle
    glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f( 5.0f,  -5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.0f,  -5.0f, -5.0f);

    //left side triangle
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f( -5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.0f,  -5.0f, -5.0f);

    //bottom triangle
    glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f( -5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 5.0f,  -5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.0f,  -5.0f, -5.0f);

    glEnd();

    //glutSolidTeapot(5.0);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutWireTeapot(5.0);
    glFlush();
}

void init()
{
    /*glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);*/
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f);//range of x,y,z axis
    //gluOrtho2D(0.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f, 0.0f);//setup the camera in 2d mode

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 'd':posx+=10;
            printf("derecha %f\n",posx);
            break;
        case 'a':posx-=10;
            printf("izquierda\n");
            break;
        case 'w':posy-=10;
            printf("arriba\n");
            break;
        case 's':posy+=10;
            printf("abajo\n");
            break;
     }

 //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 //glLoadIdentity();
 //glViewport(100.0f, 100.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f);
 //glTranslatef(posx, posy, 0.0);
 if(posx>=360)
     posx = 0;
 //glRotatef(posx, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(400, 200);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGLTest");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(drawLines);
    glutIdleFunc(drawLines);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable depth testing.  Currently it is commented out in your `init()` function.

Comment: And in addition to that you also should request a depth buffer for the context, by putting a `GLUT_DEPTH` into `glutInitDisplayMode` (and who on earth uses or teaches to use `GLUT_SINGLE` as reasonable?).

Comment: Thank you guys! It worked. Christian my teacher told us to use GLUT_SINGLE. Should I use double buffer? Do you mind explaining me the difference? Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosVargas: Using GLUT_DOUBLE instead of GLUT_SINGLE will prevent it from flickering.